# Unexpected EOF jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need help about EOF problem

```html
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('click',".deleteMe", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('#listView1').listview('refresh');
});
        $('#clickmenow').click(function(){
            var textget = $('#contributionAmount').val();
            var newPage = $('<html><head></head> <script> </script> <body><div data-role="page" id="page1"> <div data-role="main" class="content" /> <h1> Click To Enter Date </h1> <input type="text" id="dateget" /> <a href="#home" data-role="button">BACK</a>  </body> </html>')    
            //"<html> <head> </head> <body> <div data-role = 'page' id='page1'><div data-role = 'main' class = 'ui-content'/> <a href='#home' data-role='button'>BACK</a> </body>"
//'<html><head></head><body><div data-role="page" id="page1"> <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" /> <input type="text" /> <a href="#home" data-role="button">BACK</a> </body></html>'
            if(textget){
                newPage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
                $.mobile.changePage( newPage );
                var i = 0;
                $('#listView1').append('<li id="l1"><a href="#page'+(++i)+'"  > '+ textget +' </a><a id="1" class="deleteMe"></a></li>').listview('refresh');
                $('#contributionAmount').val('');
                window.alert(textget);
            } else{
                alert("empty");
            }            
        });        
      </script>
```

```js
var newPage = $('<html><head></head> <script> </script> <body><div data-role="page" id="page1"> <div data-role="main" class="content" /> <h1> Click To Enter Date </h1> <input type="text" id="dateget" /> <a href="#home" data-role="button">BACK</a>  </body> </html>')  

// the problem when i add <script></script>
```

help please :(

i don't know what should i do ?

why :( why :( ?

i want to put a pick up time

Comment: You didn't close your div tag

Comment: how can u write it please ? , i wrote <div <!--anything here--> />
not <div  <!--anything here--> > </div>